# How do I pass an environment variable into a foundry test file?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Looking to pass an alchemy rpc endpoint url that contains its api key and is stored as an environment variable in a solidity test file executed using `forge test`. I want to do so in order to use it to fork goerli testnet and potentially be able to manage different forks in the same test context. The vm cheatcode below creates a local fork of goerli at `block_number`: 
`vm.createSelectFork($GOERLI_ALCHEMY_SECRET_URL, block_number);`

How do I pass it `$GOERLI_ALCHEMY_SECRET_URL` from the environment?

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass an environment variable into a test file you can make use of `vm.envString()`:

`vm.createSelectFork(vm.envString("GOERLI_ALCHEMY_SECRET_URL"), block_number);`